# Jquery - directly i can't map the object values?

Tags: jquery

i am storing the element reference in object. later if i refer the object value, i unable to get the result..

```
    var cciApp = {};

    cciApp.widget = {
console.log($(cciApp.tools.title))//return undefined
        shuffle : function(){
            $($(cciApp.tools.title), cciApp.tools.secParent).click(function(){
                $(this).siblings('.expand-area').slideToggle().end().parent().siblings().children('.expand-area').slideUp();
            })
        }
    }



    $(document).ready(function(){
        cciApp.tools = {
            secParent : $('#Accordion'),
            title:$(cciApp.tools.secParent).find('h3')//i am not getting any result.
        }
        cciApp.widget.shuffle();
    })
```

may be returning function will help i believe. But why we need to return the stuff to retrieve the data, instead referencing just?

Answer (score 0):

Yu need to change it like this,

```
        secParent : $('#Accordion'),
        title:$('#Accordion').find('h3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
cciApp.widget = {
    console.log($(cciApp.tools.title))//return undefined
    // ...
};
```

You're calling a function **inside** an object declaration. No can do.